# ¿Cómo instalar vue/cli en manjaro linux 21.3 desde la terminal?

Tags: vue.js, git, vue-cli, manjaro

Hace poco instalé manjaro linux 21.3 y ando un poco desorientado con los comandos de pacman.

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente comando en terminal:

**npm install -g @vue/cli**

Me devuelve lo siguiente: **bash: npm: orden no encontrada**

Cuando lo intento con **sudo pacman npm install -g @vue/cli**

Me devuelve lo siguiente: **error: opción «-g» no válida**

Desde ya agradezco cualquier respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por venir por aquí en busca de ayuda @Leo20. Para que puedan ayudarte debes aporta un ejemplo mínimo y claro de lo que necesitas, deberías editar tu pregunta,. Puedes ayudarte visitando el centro de ayuda, y [Como elaboro una buena pregunta.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) De no ser asi, probablemente eliminen tu pregunta . Tienes mucha información pulsando la _"?"_ INTERROGACION de la parte superior de tu panel donde encontraras [mucha y buena información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) que te ayudara a descubrir a fondo stackoverflow . Suerte

Comment: Será que no tienes npm instalado?

Comment: Gracias Lucas por contestar. Lamentablemente por la urgencia, cambie el OS a Windows MiniOS 10. Con respecto al npm tuve el mismo problema, la conclusión que saqué es que, hay muy poco material en español, sobre arch linux y sus distribuciones. Saludos.